# Converting a QTreeWidge in PyQt to a Table in ReportLab

Tags: python, formatting, reportlab

As tables seem almost overly complicated in ReportLab, I'm trying to determine a means to simply add (preferably through the Paragraph class, if possible) two separate texts, one on the left side of the page and the other on the right. As much as I could internet I could find no seeming explanation of how to accomplish this. So if this is possible, how do you do it?

At the end what I'm trying to pull off is converting data from a QTreeWidget in PyQT into a PDF with similar look and feel.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that accomplishing this is best done through Tables. So though it be convoluted, learning the structure of table data nested lists was the way to go. The key for converting QTreeWidget data goes along the lines of the codes below, in that you have to dynamically append both data and cell styling as you work your way through the table data.

Assuming the QTreeWidget's composition is simply items with two columns of text (0, and 1), the below works.

```
from reportlab.lib.units import inch
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table, TableStyle

pdf = SimpleDocTemplate("TreeWidgetPDF.pdf", pagesize = letter)
data = []
tStyle = []

for x in QTreeWidgetData.findItems("*", Qt.MatchWildcard, 0):
    project = str(x.text(0))
    data.append([project, x.text(1)])
    tStyle.append(('BACKGROUND', (0, cell), (1, cell), 'YELLOW'))
    tStyle.append(('FONTSIZE', (0, cell), (1, cell), 12))
    cell+=1

    for y in range(x.childCount()):
        data.append([str(x.child(y).text(0)), str(x.child(y).text(1))])
        tStyle.append(('ALIGN', (1, cell), (1, cell), 'RIGHT'))
        tStyle.append(('LEFTPADDING', (0, cell), (0, cell), 15))
        cell+=1

        for z in range(x.child(y).childCount()):
            data.append([x.child(y).child(z).text(0), x.child(y).child(z).text(1)])
            tStyle.append(('ALIGN', (1, cell), (1, cell), 'RIGHT'))
            tStyle.append(('LEFTPADDING', (0, cell), (0, cell), 30))
            cell+=1

        # And so on and so forth. You could probably iterate through this in a 
        # While loop so you don't have to manually nest your for statements.

parts = []
styledTable = Table(data, [6 * inch, 1 * inch, 0])
styledTable.setStyle(TableStyle(tStyle))
parts.append(table_with_style)
pdf.build(parts)
```